# Sed command giving unexpected result

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

Below is the shell script I am trying to find the meaning.

```
sed 's/19984 $/98400 /' | sed 's/19992 $/99200 /'
```

I expect 19984 $ will get replaced with 98400 and this string will be passed to next sed command which replace 19992 $ with 99200 .

But when I executed the script below with sample input

```
echo "19984 $ need to be  replaced with 98400  "| sed 's/19984 $/98400 /' | sed 's/19992 $/99200 /'
```

I get the same string

```
"19984 $ need to be  replaced with 98400"
```

I hope something I am missing here. Please help me. I am new to shell scripts.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sed, `$` is a reserved character to you have to escape it (`\$`) to be parsed properly:

```
$ echo "19984 $ need to be  replaced with 98400  "| sed 's/19984 \$/98400 /' 
98400  need to be  replaced with 98400
```

All together:

```
$ echo "19984 $ need to be  replaced with 98400  "| sed 's/19984 \$/98400 /' | sed 's/19992 \$/99200 /'
98400  need to be  replaced with 98400
```

---

So you need to keep it like it is.

`$` can mean a lot of things:
- a normal character.
- end of line.
- name of a variable.

The way you got the code it means the second case: end of line:

```
$ echo "19984 " | sed 's/19984 $/98400 /'
98400
$ echo "19984 something" | sed 's/19984 $/98400 /'
19984 something
```

so sed will match just the cases in which the line ends with `19984`. Otherwise it won't match.

Comment: Ok that is nice. But I am studying an old code in which they kept the code as it is. Then what would have they meant

Comment: Just updated my answer. Your original code means end of line, I hope the examples help to understand it.

Comment: That's what I am looking for! Thank you very much Mr Fedorqui